# How will i create pdf file pulling information from lead

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i have a checkbox in the lead entity.When i check on the checkbox,a PDF Note should produce
pulling information from the Lead form and is emailed.Here how will i create a pdf note pulling
information from Lead and email?Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks
Adhars

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already solved your problem, the best way to do this would be to write an SSRS report that then exports to PDF.  You can have your button link directly to the report with the Export to PDF parameter in the querystring.